# Why is jquery clone cloning the parent but not its children?

Tags: jquery, clone

I´ve a parent div withs its child like this:

```
<div id="padre" class="demo">
 <ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue ui-sortable">
  <li id="app1" class="ui-state-default toolTip">
   <div id="00" class="AppPadre"></div>
```

So when I clone my parent div with then next line:

```
var $copia = $('#padre>*').clone();
```

and I print my cloned variable it only shows:

```
<div id="padre" class="demo">
 <ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue ui-sortable">
```

Does anyone has any idea why is it only copying the 1st 2 levels??
Thanks in advance.
Just after the copy I´m removing all subelements of "padre" with $('#padre>*').remove(); and it does remove all the subelements but when i do the append it only appends the 1st subelement of "padre".

Comment: What are you trying to clone? `$('#padre>*')` will clone all its children's.

Comment: You mean to do var $copia = $('#padre').clone();?

Comment: When given proper HTML, your `.clone()` statement seems to work just fine.  See this working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Sja7Z/.  If you are trying to do something different, the you must explain your question better.

Comment: I´m trying to clone all the subelements, then when I resize the browser I remove all subelements of padre and the when I get back to the original resolution; I append the copy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't close the tags correctly:

```
<div id="padre" class="demo">

     <ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue ui-sortable">
        <li id="app1" class="ui-state-default toolTip"><li>
     </ul>

    <div id="00" class="AppPadre"></div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E8uJm/

---

edit: Try the following:

```
$('#padre').children().clone();
$("#clone").append($copia);
$('#padre').remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E8uJm/2/

Comment: This is likely the issue unless the OP didn't show us the actual HTML.  `.clone()` clones the entire tree, not just part way down.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't think that is the case.. he is just sharing a snippet of his code. Ex: Definitely there are more `<li>`'s and so the closing part of the `ul` and `li` is missing.

Comment: @Vega - do you have another explanation?  The OP's code works just fine with proper HTML.  See a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Sja7Z/

Comment: if the DOCTYPE of the page is XHTML Strict this markup is problematic especially in IE.

Comment: Actually I did close it its just that i did´nt put the closing tags in the example. But thanks for for advise.

Comment: @jfriend00 I know and i think OP didn't explain what he wanted to do

Comment: if i do a new file with the code from the link it works but when i try to implement it it didn´t work, could it be that it doesn´t work because just after the cloning i remove all the subelements from "padre"??

Comment: @linker85 try the updated fiddle and check the result with firebug, does this work?

Comment: Ok i somehow manage to solve it by putting: 
    $copia = $('#padre').children().clone();
just after i load all my subelements(i was loading it outside from the onready function in an external function that was being called by the onready) in "padre". So when I do the resize i empty al "padre" subelemnts and i just append the clone in "padre" like this: 
        $('#padre>*').remove();
    $('#padre').append($copia);

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var $copia = $('#padre>*').clone(true, true);
```

Comment: The two arguments to `.clone()` only control data and events cloning.  They don't affect the cloning of the objects themselves.  Clone is always a deep clone.  See the [jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) for an explanation.

Comment: Clone already does the deep cloning. The two arguments are for cloning events and data.